# BeautifulSoup4 import error

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, importerror

I'm trying to build a python code to check if a string contains HTML code. I've tried many times on re-intalling *BeautifulSoup4* library by using `pip3 install beautifulsoup4` and `pip3 install lxml` and it already shows me this:

```
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4
```

But whenever I tried to import beautifulsoup it came out with this error code:

```
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested
```

What should I do to import the *beautifulsoup* library correctly?

Here is the chunk of code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
body = "..."
bool(BeautifulSoup(body, "body.parser").find())
```

Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: `BeautifulSoup` is importing fine, it is the parser (`body.parser`) that is throwing the error. Look at the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) for more information on the parsers

Comment: Use `BeautifulSoup(body, "lxml")` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I consider the first sentence in your query first, 'I'm trying to build a python code to check if a string contains HTML code.'

BeautifulSoup is most probably *not* the tool one would use for this because it has been engineered to take almost any string as input, and produce a parsed HTML structure for that string.

For instance, here I input a string with no tags and all and BS gives back a complete page, even producing a `body` element for that page.

```
>>> import bs4
>>> s = 'this represents just about any string'
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')
>>> soup
<html><body><p>this represents just about any string</p></body></html>
>>> soup.find_all('body')
[<body><p>this represents just about any string</p></body>]
```

Here's an alternative, somewhat crude approach using HTMLParser. HTMLParser is in the standard Python library.

```
>>> from html.parser import HTMLParser
>>> class IsItHTML(HTMLParser):
...     def __init__(self):
...         HTMLParser.__init__(self)
...         self.found = False
...     def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
...         self.found = True
...     def __call__(self):
...         return self.found
... 
>>> isitHTML = IsItHTML()
>>> s = 'this represents just about any string'
>>> isitHTML.feed(s)
>>> isitHTML()
False
>>> s = '<body>something</body>'
>>> isitHTML.feed(s)
>>> isitHTML()
True
```

The main criticism I have for this approach is that it involves traversing every tag in an HTML input.

Regarding your second principal question: how do I import BS correctly? I think you're doing that. The problem would appear to be with `BeautifulSoup(body, "body.parser").find()`. I have no idea what that might mean.